# Capital letters and blank spaces in column title

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product VARCHAR,
    quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(product, quantity)
VALUES 
('product_01', '800'),
('product_02', '300'),
('product_03', '200'),
('product_04', '500'),
('product_05', '600'),
('product_06', '400');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
product_name  |   Product Name   |
--------------|------------------|---------
product_01    |   product_01     |
product_02    |   product_02     | 
product_03    |   product_03     |
product_04    |   product_04     |
product_05    |   product_05     |
product_06    |   product_06     |
```

---

My issue is that I want to name the second column in my results `Product Name` with

1. **capital letters** for both words and
2. **blank space** between the word Product and Name.

In [postgresSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b6043c6fcadd8cf3a303c47568dd47f) it works without any problem using this query:

```
SELECT
iv.product AS product_name,
iv.product AS "Product Name"
FROM inventory iv;
```

However, when I apply the same query to `redshift` the column title looks like this `productname`. 
Both the **captial letters** and **blank space** get deleted.

Is there a way to display it in `redshift` the same way it is done in `postgresSQL`?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can always use some unique single word alias for each column, and then map to whatever string you want in your presentation layer.

Comment: According to their documentation it looks like spaces should be preserved but not capitals. [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible (nor adviseable) to have spaces in column names.
From the AWS Redshift [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html):

> Standard SQL identifiers adhere to a set of rules and must:
>
> Begin with an ASCII single-byte alphabetic character or underscore
> character, or a UTF-8 multibyte character two to four bytes long.
>
> Subsequent characters can be ASCII single-byte alphanumeric
> characters, underscores, or dollar signs, or UTF-8 multibyte
> characters two to four bytes long.
>
> Be between 1 and 127 bytes in length, not including quotation marks
> for delimited identifiers.
>
> **Contain no quotation marks and no spaces.**
>
> Not be a reserved SQL key word.

It is possible, however, to preserve capital letters in column names:

> To return column names in uppercase, set the
> describe_field_name_in_uppercase configuration parameter to true.

Best of luck in your endeavours